# How to pre-design circuit before buying?

Tags: hardware

I am wanting to make a simple circuit that takes input from a movement sensor and plays a sound response.

To do this I think an ESP32 microcontroler would be optimal?

But how does one go about identifying parts and making sure they are compatible before buying?

For example I have no idea what sensor, speaker or battery sources to use. How does a total noob go about finding all this out in an efficient way?

Comment: Step one: read similar projects and tutorials. Step two: prototype using modules, breadboards, and wires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Step #1: Steal! Search engines are your friend.
- Step #2: (see step #1).

Look for published projects using parts that you want to use or to find out what parts someone else used, and how they connected them & coded for them.

Look up the datasheets for the parts you propose to use and read at least the introductions, to decide if they meet your needs. If you're project is for learning, not going into a bigger project (yet), you may not need this step if someone else's project has shown you the way. When you eventually come to designing your own, this step will be important.

As a beginner, copying from others is really the best/quickest way to 1) make stuff happen; and 2) not (or be less likely to...) blow up parts that cost money and take time to replace.

Once you've built a couple of projects you'll start to see common techniques of coding and of building circuits, that will lead you to more questions. (See step #1 above).

There's more, like learning some basic electrical and electronic theory and practice, if you haven't already, but that can come a little later and will make more sense when you have some hands-on experience.